# Knapsack without repetition

Tags: arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using std::vector;

int o_w(int W, const vector<int> &w) {
  vector<int> c(W+1);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < w.size(); ++i) {
      for(int j = W; j - w[i] >= 0; --j) {
            c[j] = std::max(c[j], c[j - w[i]] + w[i]);
      }
  }
  return c[W];
}

int opti_w(int W,const std::vector<int> &w,int n){
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> value(n+1,vector<int>(W+1,0));
    for(int i=0;i<=n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<=W;j++){
            std::cout<<value[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        std::cout<<"\n";
    }

    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
      for(int j=1;j<=W;j++){
       //value[j][i]=std::max(value[j][i-1],value[j-w[i]][i-1]+w[i]);
      std::cout<<"i:"<<i<<" j:"<<j<<"\n";
      std::cout<<"value[i][j]:"<<value[i][j]<<"\n";
      std::cout<<"value[i-1][j]:"<<value[i-1][j]<<"\n";
      std::cout<<"w[i-1]:"<<w[i-1]<<"\n";
      std::cout<<"value[i-1][j-w[i-1]]:"<<value[i-1][j-w[i-1]]<<"\n";
      std::cout<<"value[i-1][j-w[i-1]]+w[i-1]:"<<value[i-1][j-w[i-1]]+w[i-1]<<"\n";
      value[i][j]=std::max(value[i-1][j],  value[i-1][j-w[i-1]] +w[i-1]  );
      }
    }
    
     for(int i=0;i<=n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<=W;j++){
            std::cout<<value[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        std::cout<<"\n";
    }

    return value[n][W];
   // return value[W][n];
}

int main() {
  int n, W;
  std::cin >> W >> n;
  vector<int> w(n);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    std::cin >> w[i];
  }
  std::cout<<opti_w(W, w, n);
  //std::cout << o_w(W, w) << '\n';
}
```

In function opti_w I am somehow using the wrong formula or getting something wrong due to which I am unable to get correct values because sometime j-[w-1] becomes negative hence unwanted elements gets accessed.

Function o_w is correct and can be used to verify answers.

How can I approach to resolve the issue and whats incorrect in the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
   for(int j=1;j<=W;j++){
      value[i][j] = value[i-1][j];
      if(w[i-1]<=j){
       value[i][j]=std::max(value[i][j],  value[i-1][j-w[i-1]] +w[i-1]  );
       }
      }
    }
```

I just changed the code inside if(w[i-1]<=j) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. Why not put your `std::max` statement under an `if` condition to take care of the case when `j-w[i-1]` makes no sense?

Comment: Thanks @zhanga.
It solved that some problem.
Now I am one step close to solve the problem.

Comment: I got it the problem lies in using i or i-1 at code inside if statement